# How to address backend host with axios, when frontend and backend are in virtual docker network

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, docker-compose, axios

I'm building a simple Website with login, and my vue-frontend needs to retrieve user data from my nodejs-backend which connects to a sql database.
I decided to use docker-compose for this, and as I understand, docker-compose sets up a network automatically for the services that are mentioned in my docker-compose.yml.

What doesn't seem to work, is the way I address the backend in my code.
I suspect that it might be because of the way I use axios to send a request to my backend.

I have inspected the default docker-network and was able to ping from my frontend to my backend using the dns names I found in the network-configuration.
But using the same names inside my code didn't work.

What does work, is mapping a host port to my exposed api port and using http://localhost:5000 as address, but this defeats the purpose of a docker network.

my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
    vue-frontend:
        image: flowmotion/vue-js-frontend
        ports:
            - 8070:80
        depends_on:
            - db-user-api

    db-user-api:
        image: flowmotion/user-db-api
        environment:
            - PORT=5000
        ports:
            - 5000:5000 #only needed if docker network connection can't be established
```

the Vue-fontend files in question:

Login.vue

```
methods: {
    async login() {
      try {
        const response = await authenticationService.login({
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password
        });
        this.$store.dispatch("setToken", response.data.token);
        this.$store.dispatch("setUser", response.data.user);
        this.$router.push({ path: "/" });
      } catch (error) {
        this.showError = true;
        this.error = error.response.data.error;
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

authenticationService.js

```
import api from "@/services/api";

export default {
  login(credentials) {
    return api().post("login", credentials);
  }
};
```

api.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import config from '../config/config';
export default () => {
    return axios.create({
        baseURL: config.userBackendServer
    });
};
```

config.js ()

```
module.exports = {
    userBackendServer: 'http://cl-dashboard_db-user-api_1:5000' //this doesn't seem to work
};

//using 'http://localhost:5000' works if ports are mapped to host machine.
```

expected result would be my backend doing a sql lookup.

actuel result is, instead of connecting to my backend my frontend gives me a 404 status and my backend is never reached

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you are correct assuming containers in the docker network can talk to each other without opening any ports to the outer world.

point is- **your vue app is not in any container- it is served from a container as a js script file to your browser**, which is the one sending the requests to your node backend. since your browser is by any means not inside the docker network - you must use the outer port mapping (`localhost:5000` in your case) to reach the backend.

let me know if you have any more questions about that.

Comment: ok, this makes sense. So for deployment, would I need to specify the serving ip address/URI with the port specified in my docker-compose.yml?
like this:
userBackendServer: 'URItoMyApp:5000'

Comment: put it as an environment variable in your `.env` file, in the vue app root directory. for now its is going to be `VUE_APP_API_ROOT=http://localhost:500/` and on production change it to your server hostname. your backend production container is supposed to be mapped to the host default ports (80 and 443) and therefore you wont need to specify any port number.

Comment: What about when the bind the ports not to the host machine but to a given network? For instance, to avoid exposing the services ports directly to the host, I have set my containers to use the Docker interface. Now I can't connect my servers to themselves. Any ideas?

Comment: @GustavoSilva can you tell me more about how this "binding to a given network" is done? im not sure a got you. if its on github you can link it here and ill take a look

Comment: @EfratLevitan, It's not on GitHub. I have a setup similar to above. The difference is that I'm using Docker network's interface IP instead of binding the services ports to the host's directly. In summary, my port have a configuration similar to: port: - 172.17.0.1:3000:5000

Comment: in which address do you access the container from your browser? this is the that address should be given to the frontend as `VUE_APP_API_ROOT`.

Comment: I had something equivalent, yes. I do not access containers from the outside that easily. My host's nginx configuration does proxy reverses accordingly. Remember I'm only exposing the containers' ports to the docker network.

Comment: @GustavoSilva if the container is not accessible outside the docker network, the frontend app wont be able to send requests

Comment: That makes sense. I had hopes containers could communicate with each other if they were all on the same network, regardless of which network drivers they use (br0, dckr0, or whatever)

Comment: @GustavoSilva they do, but a frontend app is not inside a container- its running from the browser. (refer to my answer)

Comment: Yea, I'm following. I guess I have to look at the structure again and check what can be done. Thanks for your help! :+1:

Comment: @EfratLevitan, as a webapp noob, I don't understand this: I would have imagine that the front container is the front to the client. So any request to that front will do something inside, which is unknown to the user - reaching to the back container and get a response. But what happens here is that the user actually sees what the front does and can do it himself. 1. Is that fine? Isn't it ugly to use two addresses for one website? 2. Doesn't it require that CORS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) which is a hack for this scenario? Thanks!

Comment: @hudac 1. frontend apps runs on the client side and yes, he can view them and manipulate them as much as he wants, this is why any sensitive action (like addressing the DB) should be performed from the backend side and never from the client. 2. you can use dev proxy to spare the CORS problems, here is how to do it
: https://medium.com/js-dojo/how-to-deal-with-cors-error-on-vue-cli-3-d78c024ce8d3

Comment: @EfratLevitan I'm not talking about dev, I'm talking about production. Is it the appropriate way web apps work? e.g. I go to myapp.com, and each click that requires db access (and not just frontend js changes) goes hiddenly to myapp.back.com ? Is that the proper way to do it ? I thought CORS is just for external (not myapp.com address) content.

Comment: @hudac Correct, CORS headers shouldn't be used on production. The usual architecture puts a proxy server (say nginx) that serves the frontend file, and redirect `/api/*` requests to the backend server. example: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#docker-nginx

Comment: @EfratLevitan, yes, I read about it. The only thing I don't understand in that method is: 1. specifically in the example you attached, I think I don't see any different route than root '/'. 2. If there's another route - does nginx pass it directly there? or it pass through my js code? I mean - let's say I have code that goes to a db and for each entry it gets, it makes some manipulation, then it shows it nicely  in gui. If nginx routs my request not through my js code, wouldn't I just get the raw data ?

Comment: BTW maybe this example doesn't reflect the use case I'm trying to depict. It says on your link: "If you are using Vue CLI along with a backend framework that handles static assets as part of its deployment". I think my use case is a db. not static assets.

Comment: ok, I found this example https://github.com/wkrzywiec/kanban-board/blob/master/kanban-ui/default.conf - nginx reverse proxy which redirects internally the calls for /api/*.
Thanks!

Comment: Hello, this is an old question and I'm running into the same issue. I understood what was being talked and I will try soon. My question is for @EfratLevitan, at one point you mentioned: `and on production change it to your server hostname`. How would that be accomplished, in the sense that, you would have to know your production URL at build time since you can't alter the variable after that. Am I right? Or with Vue, you can do that? Since I'm using react, I know that after I build it, then I can't alter that value.

Comment: @Vivere In production you usually put proxy to achieve same domain name for the frontend and the backend (otherwise you face CORS) so you can eliminate the hostname from the requested URL and by default the browser will use the frontend domain name as the hostname (for example you send an AJAX to "/api/image1.png") without hostname.